# Systematically remove strings from a cell

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I have a cell `name1` (nx1)

```
a.mat
b.mat
c.mat
...
z.mat
```

I'd like to create a cell `name2` in which all the .mat have been removed so I'll have this

```
a
b
c
...
z
```

I could create a loop and remove the .mat with `strsplit` or `fileparts` but this would be very cumbersome. Anyone has a shortcut how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`erase`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/erase.html) since R2016b

```
name1New = erase( name1, '.mat' );
```

Or `strrep` since forever

```
name1New = strrep( name1, '.mat', '' );
```

Both of these will remove all instances of `.mat` within the cell, which is usually fine for file names and their extensions, but if for some reason you need to strictly confine this to `.mat` at the *end* of the strings, you can use `regexprep`

```
name1New = regexprep( name1, '\.mat$', '' );
```

---

Example:

```
name = {'blah.mat', 'foo.mat', 'bar.matTest.mat'};
erase(name,'.mat')
ans =
  1×3 cell array
    {'blah'}    {'foo'}    {'barTest'}
regexprep( name, '\.mat$', '' )
ans =
  1×3 cell array
    {'blah'}    {'foo'}    {'bar.matTest'}
```